# Do single name stock option volatility surfaces exhibit steeper volatility smiles after stock price crash episodes?

Tags: options, option-pricing, implied-volatility, volatility-smile

In index options, there was not much of a smile (on the put-side) until the 1987 market crash.

I'm wondering if the same applies to single name stocks? That is, do price crashes in individual stocks trigger smiles in their option surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very very common that implied vol, and particularty that of OTM puts, increases after crashes, even after limited losses.

A market maker will have a tendency to increase its volatility on the left side of a smile if a stock price drops, because the risk inherent to that stock is considered higher.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks much. Are there any references, studies, or papers that document this?

Comment: You can have a look at the following sources :

- http://www.sr-sv.com/modelling-the-relation-between-volatility-and-returns/#:~:text=The%20two%20relations%20between%20volatility,acts%20in%20the%20opposite%20direction.

-[link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222881415_Why_are_stock_returns_and_volatility_negatively_correlated)

Comment: I think the "notion" that you are referring to is the "volatility leverage effect". Check it out on google, you will find plenty of references.